# How to be sure that my e2e tests are executed correct?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

When I setup that protractor slowly execute tests, I saw that he is all the time on login page, and on the end of executing tests he logged in.

But all tests are executed correctly.

There is 160 tests, 90% page objects (fields, buttons...) is selected by "all" and "xpath":

```
element.all(by.xpath('/xpath');
```

I scare that my tests not works as I expect, but that protractor "execute them correct"?

Comment: Are you asking for help about flaky tests?

Comment: @Attersson No, I am just not sure that I made correct tests. 
Ectually I am not sure in that does protractor execute correct this tests.
I can't see what protractor doing.
Only on the end I see that tests are executed correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about gathering and displaying information on the tests executions.

You can begin with using the --verbose option.

Second, there are reporters available such as [protractor-beautiful-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-beautiful-reporter) for Angular

Comment: I will try.
Thanks for help.